# ProgrammingPhoenix Rumbl.Web is not loaded

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to implement the login feature as part of the book and am running into issues:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/user_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:39: undefined      
function page_path/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in   
Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

My module looks like this:

```
defmodule Rumbl.UserController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller
  plug :authenticate when action in [:index, :show]
  alias Rumbl.User

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Repo.all(User)
    render conn, "index.html", users: users
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Repo.get(Rumbl.User, id)
    render conn, "show.html", user: user
  end

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.registration_changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "#{user.name} created!")
        |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  defp authenticate(conn, _opts) do
    if conn.assigns.current_user do
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in to access that page")
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt()
    end
  end
end
```

And I know my :controller comes from here:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Web do
  @moduledoc """
  A module that keeps using definitions for controllers,
  views and so on.

  This can be used in your application as:

      use Rumbl.Web, :controller
      use Rumbl.Web, :view

  The definitions below will be executed for every view,
  controller, etc, so keep them short and clean, focused
  on imports, uses and aliases.

  Do NOT define functions inside the quoted expressions
  below.
  """

  def model do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema

      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query
    end
  end

  def controller do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Controller

      alias Rumbl.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Query

      import Rumbl.Router.Helpers
      import Rumbl.Gettext

    end
  end

  def view do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"

      # Import convenience functions from controllers
      import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]

      # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
      use Phoenix.HTML

      import Rumbl.Router.Helpers
      import Rumbl.ErrorHelpers
      import Rumbl.Gettext
    end
  end

  def router do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Router
    end
  end

  def channel do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Channel

      alias Rumbl.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Query
      import Rumbl.Gettext
    end
  end

  @doc """
  When used, dispatch to the appropriate controller/view/etc.
  """
  defmacro __using__(which) when is_atom(which) do
    apply(__MODULE__, which, [])
  end
end
```

I've inspected the code a number of times and can't see anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check your `router.ex` to find this line `get "/", PageController, :index`

Comment: 1. Show us your router. 2. Try user_path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is messed with your router. Try `mix phoenix.routes` in your console. Then find appropriate `something_path` function and use it. Sample output.

```
page_path  GET     /           Module.PageController :index
user_path  GET     /login      Module.UserController :login
user_path  GET     /users      Module.UserController :index
user_path  GET     /users/:id  Module.UserController :show
user_path  POST    /users      Module.UserController :create
user_path  PATCH   /users/:id  Module.UserController :update
           PUT     /users/:id  Module.UserController :update
user_path  DELETE  /users/:id  Module.UserController :delete
```

So for example if I wanted to redirect to redirect to main user path I would use `user_path`, etc..

And if you can, please show us your router and result of mix `phoenix.routes` task.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I was missing `page_path  GET     /           Module.PageController :index`. What was the clue that made you think it was to do with my routes? It's strange that it would fail to compile like that because of a missing route no? If this was django, it would have run fine and once you made the http request, it would give you a "route not matched" error.

Comment: @clery00 these functions are generated based on routes and error said explicitly undefined function page_path....

Comment: I see makes sense, thanks. It's taking me a while to understand how these macros work in practice - that these functions are being generated at compile time based on the routes available. Thanks vm.